# What is Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlImpl?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, office-interop

I am building a small helper to fetch and populate all the controls of a ribbon group inside a collection.

```
Option Strict On
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon

Private Function GetChildControls(Group As RibbonGroup) As IEnumerable(Of RibbonControl)

    Dim ChildControls As New List(Of RibbonControl)

    Dim SubControls As IEnumerable(Of RibbonControl) = Group.Items
    ChildControls.AddRange(SubControls)

    ' ...
    ' Some recursive call over SubControls to get the children of each child (not relevant here)
    ' ...

    Return ChildControls

End Function
```

Code breaks at `ChildControls.AddRange(SubControls)`, with the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControl[]' to type  Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlImpl[]'.'

I cannot find any reference at all on `RibbonControlImpl`. The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon?view=vsto-2017) is silent, and - surprisingly - so are [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=RibbonControlImpl) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=RibbonControlImpl).

Changing `ChildControls.AddRange(SubControls)` into `SubControls.ToList.ForEach(Sub(p) ChildControls.Add(p))` does not work either, but a classic `For Each` does the trick:

```
For Each MySubControl As RibbonControl In SubControls
    ChildControls.Add(MySubControl)
Next
```

I would like to understand what is happening here? Is `Impl` a suffix to interface types to signify something? Maybe 'Impl' stands for 'Implementation'? I could not find any information on this either.

Comment: According to this http://whatdll.com/type/RibbonControlImpl.html, it's part of the assembly Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation, so, yes, it has something to do with implementation. This would be an *VSTO-internal* library for supporting the RIbbon Designer (as opposed to Ribbon XML). VSTO does a lot of stuff behind-the-scenes to make Ribbon controls "behave" like Windows Forms controls, making life simpler for the developer. In the library you'll find various namespaces and interfaces, including `Microsoft.Office.Tools:Ribbon`.

Comment: Yes that was the only "useful" entry I got on my google search. Microsoft however does not seem to document this namespace.

Comment: It wouldn't, as it's for internal use...

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts, no idea if I am right; what do you think?

`Office.Ribbon.RibbonControl` is an interop interface, hence [cannot be used as a generic type across assemblies](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/vbteam/troubleshooting-errors-when-embedding-type-information-doug-rothaus/). A guess would be that Microsoft implemented a non-interop `RibbonControlImp` wrapper to which `RibbonControl` is implicitly cast every time it is referenced as a generic type.

No idea how this would be achieved, but that would explain why `For Each ... Next` does not throw the error, whilst relying on generic collections does.